bspwm black screen
I am trying to install a new window manager and went for bspwm. I have installed it and sxhkd with apt like so.
sudo apt install bspwm sxhkd
I made the directories bspwm,sxhkd in ~/.config and the config files bspwmrc, sxhkdrc.
When i log out of my Ubuntu and log in choosing to use bspwm as my window manager and log in again all i get is a black screen and no of the short cuts work
my bspwnrc file looks like so
#!/bin/bash 

xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr
sxhkd &

bspc config vorder_width 2
bspc config window_gap   0

bspc config split_ratio     0.62
bspc config focus_follows_pointer   true
bspc config pointer_modifier    mod1
 
bspc config automatic_scheme    spiral

My sxhkdrc file looks like so
# make sxhkd reload its configuration files
alt + Escape
    pkill -USR1 -x sxhkd
 
# quit or restart bspwm
alt + shift + {q,r}
    bspc {quit,wm -r}
 
# create a new terminal window or swap the current one to the biggest one in the screen 
alt + {_,shift + }Return
    {st, bspc node -s biggest.local}
 
# close or kill a window
alt + {_,shift + }c
    bspc node -{k,c}
 
# change the window state
alt + {t,ctrl + t,l,f}
    bspc node -t {tiled,pseudo_tiled,floating,fullscreen}
 
# expand a window by moving one of its side outward
super + alt + {h,j,k,l}
    bspc node -z {left -20 0,bottom 0 20,top 0 -20,right 20 0}
 
# focus or send a window to the given desktop
alt + {_,shift + }{1-9,0}
    bspc {desktop -f,node -d} '^{1-9,10}'

